# Concurrent access to Neo4j from desktop apps

Tags: neo4j

I am planning to create a desktop app (Java or C# WPF) which would be used by multiple users. The requirements are such that a Graph DB like Neo4j fits perfectly into the scheme of things. I have done some investigations and it looks really good. I am working on the community edition. Now here is the problem. From what I have observed, I am able to make only one connection to the database. The moment I try to make a connection from another instance I get an error. Even accessing on localhost:7474 gives an error.

Is this by design? I understand that in a web App, I can still use a static reference to a single DB instance and work with it. But in a desktop app scenario how do I ensure that multiple users are able to access the database from their apps?

Answer (score 1):

Your app instances can access the same neo4j server through its REST API. There is no need to directly connect to the DB.

[Here is a page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html) that shows you how to do that in Java.

Comment: Hi @cybersam, Thanks. But from whatever I have read , I believe that the REST API access is very slow as compared to other options like the Core API. So can I assume that the REST API is the ONLY option I have for my scenario? Also from your experience do you believe that REST API is a good option for multi client production grade solution/product?